# Unable to import Flask to Kivy iOS

Tags: python, ios, ipad, flask, kivy

I want to import [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) to Kivy iOS project and create a server on iPad.

But when I'm running I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                             
       File "/Users/macuser/kivy-ios/servi-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 15, in <module>  
     ImportError: No module named flask                                                                            
    2016-05-25 15:25:03.213 servi[40042:547076] Application quit abnormally!              
    2016-05-25 15:25:03.220 servi[40042:547076] Leaving
```

If I deploy the same code on OS X shell (using the command `python main.py`) everything is OK, but in XCode (7.3) it's not.

How can I import Flask to Kivy project? I have Flask on my Mac (`sudo -H pip install flask`, if someone needs)

My code (`main.py`): (last line, the error)

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import urllib
import flask
from flask import Flask, Response, request

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='', static_folder='public')
app.add_url_rule('/', 'root', lambda: app.send_static_file('index.html'))


@app.route('/api/comments', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def comments_handler():
    with open('comments.json', 'r') as f:
        comments = json.loads(f.read())

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_comment = request.form.to_dict()
        new_comment['id'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
        comments.append(new_comment)

        with open('comments.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(comments, indent=4, separators=(',', ': ')))

    return Response(
        json.dumps(comments),
        mimetype='application/json',
        headers={
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 3000)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Using [React Native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) allow you to write Native Android/ IOS applications. You can however use React Native, [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) and [Flask Rest API](https://flask-restless.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to interchange data between your local android device and the remote server.